Why could the Israelites not drive out the Jebusites? Joshua 15:63
We read in Joshua 3:10

And Joshua said, “By this you will know that the living God is among
you, and that He will assuredly drive out from you the Canaanite, the
Hittite, the Hivite, the Perizzite, the Girgashite, the Amorite, and
the Jebusite.

We then read in Joshua 15:63

Now as for the Jebusites, the inhabitants of Jerusalem, the sons of
Judah could not drive them out; so the Jebusites live with the sons of
Judah in Jerusalem to this day.

Why could the Israelites specifically not drive out the Jebusites?

The Israelites' failure to drive out the Jebusites was a direct consequence of their disobedience to the Lord's command, as given to Moses in Deuteronomy 7:1-2 and Numbers 33:51-53, requiring them to completely destroy and expel the Canaanites. Achan's Sin, described in Joshua 7, marks the beginning of their troubles.

1 But the Israelites were unfaithful in regard to the devoted things; Achan son of Karmi, the son of Zimri, the son of Zerah, of the tribe of Judah, took some of them. So the Lord’s anger burned against Israel........10 The Lord said to Joshua, “Stand up! What are you doing down on your face? 11 Israel has sinned; they have violated my covenant, which I commanded them to keep. They have taken some of the devoted things; they have stolen, they have lied, they have put them with their own possessions. 12 That is why the Israelites cannot stand against their enemies; they turn their backs and run because they have been made liable to destruction. I will not be with you anymore unless you destroy whatever among you is devoted to destruction.

Due to their disobedience, the Israelites' enemies remained in their territories. According to Judges 3:1-6, the Lord kept some nations to test Israel's faith and teach warfare to their descendants.

1 These are the nations the Lord left to test all those Israelites who had not experienced any of the wars in Canaan 2 (he did this only to teach warfare to the descendants of the Israelites who had not had previous battle experience): 3 the five rulers of the Philistines, all the Canaanites, the Sidonians, and the Hivites living in the Lebanon mountains from Mount Baal Hermon to Lebo Hamath. 4 They were left to test the Israelites to see whether they would obey the Lord’s commands, which he had given their ancestors through Moses. 5 The Israelites lived among the Canaanites, Hittites, Amorites, Perizzites, Hivites and Jebusites. 6 They took their daughters in marriage and gave their own daughters to their sons, and served their gods.

The central theme in the Book of Judges is summarized in Zechariah 4:6: "not by might nor by power, but by my spirit." The typical cycle in the Judges involves;

The Israelites sinning,
Subsequent oppression by the nations the Lord's left,
the Israelites repenting,
The Lord delivering them through a chosen judge to carry out His plan.

In the end, it wasn't only the Jebusites who remained; the Philistines, Canaanites, Hittites, Amorites, Perizzites and Hivites were also left in the land.

+1. Good answer. I missed the Judges 3 reference, that’s a good one. I appreciate it!

The Jebusites might have been driven out of their pastoral and farming lands, but not from their capital city: Jerusalem. This city that was blessed with strong natural fortifications, which had been strengthened over centuries of occupation by the people of the land, whether Jebusites or Canaanites. Jodi Magness, author of Jerusalem throughout the Ages, summarizes:

By 1050 bce, Jerusalem had been inhabited for nearly two millennia.
The settlement was confined to a small hill to the south of the [current] Temple
Mount called the southeastern hill, with the Gihon Spring at the foot
of the eastern slope... Over the centuries, Jerusalem’s pre-Israelite
inhabitants fortified the settlement with a wall and dug an elaborate
system of underground tunnels to provide safe access to the spring
even in times of siege.

Access to water, centuries of fortification, and a natural setting which narrowed attack routes through mountainous approaches enabled the city's residents to endure long sieges. These archaeological findings are confirmed in the biblical description of David's successful taking of the city.
1 Chron. 11

4 Then David and all Israel went to Jerusalem, that is, Jebus, where
the inhabitants of the land were called Jebusites. 5 The inhabitants
of Jebus said to David, “You shall not enter here.” David nevertheless
captured the fortress of Zion, which is the City of David. 6 David
said, “Whoever strikes the Jebusites first shall be made chief and
captain.” Joab, the son of Zeruiah, was the first to attack; and so he
became chief. 7 David took up residence in the fortress, which
therefore was called the City of David. 8 He built up the city on all
sides, from the Millo all the way around, while Joab restored the rest
of the city. 9 David became ever more powerful, for the Lord of hosts
was with him.

The theological reason for Joshua's failure to conquer Jerusalem is a matter of opinion. It may be that we are being told that God was with David to even a greater degree than he was with Joshua, since David succeeded where Joshua failed.

+1. Thanks for the answer! Good reference.
